# How to get name of input file in Xtext

Tags: xtext

I am implementing a language where name of the file needs to be the same as name of the class.
How can I get name of the file in validator?
If I can't do that, is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can as any `EObject` for its `eResource()` and that for its `getURI()`. That will allow you to get the file name (`lastSegment`). you may want to `trimFileExtension()` first.

Comment: Thanks, I got it: 
String fileName = a.eResource().getURI().trimFileExtension().lastSegment();